# Why do still renders look sharper than animations?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm doing an scene based on the Solar System (in Cycles), with the inconvenient that when i press 'Render' and then i press 'Save the Image As' it looks better, brighter and more defined than when i press Animation.
I saved the two images as PNG (Because i needed as Alpha images for later)but when i imported them to an editing software (on this case, Adobe After Effects) I can clearly see the difference...starting from the definition of the Orbit/Line.
*I hope someone can lend me a hand about this one, i'm getting troubled.*

[image]

Comment: On your render presets, are you rendering at 100% resolution?

Comment: Oh, you are right! i really missed that one this time :(
Hmm, and about the bit depth, which one is the best? and also is there any way in order to add sightly, more color to the image?

Comment: If you are going to post process the image use a higher bit depth like 16bit. Colorwise... deal with it in afterFX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the resolution for the final render is set at 100%.

[image]

If you are going to do further compositing/postproduction/color correction in other software, render to an image sequence in a [lossless format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) using a higher bit depht like 16bit per channel.